# Getting a Band-Image using Dart and Flutterr

Tags: flutter, api, dart

so i started with a new Screen where the User can input his favorite Band.
The Plan is to display an image of this Band underneath the input field after the user clicked the Button "Search"

Im using the Wikipedia API for this.
Now the Problem:
If i enter a Bandname like "Linkin Park" and click on the Button nothing will show up. If i delete the last character of the Bandname(in this example "k") the app shows the correct image.
When i enter the API Link in the browser with the correct Bandname it will show me the correct data.

Storing the Data in Firestore works perfectly fine. Just this little problem.

`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class FavoriteBandScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavoriteBandScreenState createState() => _FavoriteBandScreenState();
}

class _FavoriteBandScreenState extends State<FavoriteBandScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String _favoriteBand = '';
  String _bandImageUrl = '';

  Future _getBandImage() async {
    // Rufe die Wikipedia-Seite der Band auf
    String encodedBandName = _favoriteBand.replaceAll(' ', '%20');

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=$encodedBandName&pithumbsize=400'));


    // Parse die Antwort als JSON
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = json.decode(response.body);

    // Hole die URL des Bandbilds
    if (jsonData['query'] != null && jsonData['query']['pages'] != null) {
      String pageKey = jsonData['query']['pages'].keys.first;
      if (jsonData['query']['pages'][pageKey] != null &&
          jsonData['query']['pages'][pageKey]['thumbnail'] != null) {
        _bandImageUrl =
            jsonData['query']['pages'][pageKey]['thumbnail']['source'];
      } else {
        _bandImageUrl = '';
      }
    } else {
      _bandImageUrl = '';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Lieblingsband eingeben'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Gib deine Lieblingsband ein:'),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    _favoriteBand = "";
                  } else {
                    _favoriteBand = value;
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            _bandImageUrl == ''
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : Image.network(_bandImageUrl),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
// Holle das Bandbild
                if (_favoriteBand != '') {
                  _getBandImage();
                }
// Speichere die Lieblingsband in der Cloud-Datenbank
                User currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
                _firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).set({
                  'favoriteBand': _favoriteBand,
                  'bandImageUrl': _bandImageUrl,
                }, SetOptions(merge: true));
              },
              child: Text('Suchen'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

Ignore the german comments :)
thanks for your help

I tryed encoding the Bandname with replacing spaces with "_" and "%20%". Both nosuccess
i also tryed adding a space in the value which is used inthe Widget build to handoverr the String_favoriteBand

Comment: Try `print`ing out the exact URI you've built before fetching it, and see if it's what you expect. Calling the URL you gave with "Linkin%20Park" inserted (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=Linkin%20Park&pithumbsize=400) appears to work fine, so it seems like you might be building a different URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wie geht's? Ich spreche auch Deutsch, werde aber nur auf Englisch antworten.

WIKIPEDIA's API call looks great. no need to "encoding" the band name LOL :)

Take a close look at how you handled `_bandImageUrl`.

`_getBandImage()` is an async function that by default has a delay. to be able to use `_bandImageUrl` you need to manage its state. To do that you first need to rearrange your codebase by introducing `initState`. Call `_getBandImage()` within the `initState` and change:

```dart
_bandImageUrl = jsonData['query']['pages'][pageKey]['thumbnail']['source'];
```

TO

```dart
image = jsonData['query']['pages'][pageKey]['thumbnail']['source'];

// check if mounted before using `setState` to avoid state error as we are working on the `initState`
if (mounted) {
    setState(() => _bandImageUrl = image);
}
```

**NOTE**

This is not the best/better way. You should consider looking into using Models for your API organization and providers to implement its service calls.

If you are still having problems. Let me know right here.

Tschau!!!